# How to Diagonal in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def diagonal(t, x, y):
    """Makes a diagonal line to the given x, y offsets and return"""
    from math import atan2, sqrt, pi
    angle = atan2(y, x) * 180 / pi
    dist = sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    lt(t, angle)
    fdbk(t, dist)
    rt(t, angle)
```

I do not understand what does the `atan2` method do. How is it calculating the angle? And why is there another method that calculates the distance?

Comment: "I do not understand what does the atan2 method do" Did you look at the documentation?

Comment: Please write the code with proper indentation and also quote the source of the code, if possible.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.atan2

Comment: The `atan2` function is not Python specific: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Comment: Atan2 is simply Tan inverse trigonometric function which gives the output in radians. So, it is multiplied by 180/pi to convert it into degrees.

Comment: @ABcDexter Thank you Dexter. Still, i do not know what tan inverse function is. Should i first go learn some maths? or do u know where can i learn about it?

Comment: @MatiSandacz Yes you should. Start reading with wiki links provided above, also here is a good link. https://brilliant.org/wiki/inverse-trigonometric-functions/

Comment: You should use `hypot` function instead of `sqrt(x**2+y**2)`

Answer (score 1):

[Atan2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.atan2) is simply Tan [inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions) trignometric function which gives the output in radians. So, it is multiplied by 180/pi to convert it into degrees.

**dist** is for calculating [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between x and y.

And for the **lt(t, angle)** and **rt(t, angle)**, i can guess that they stand for Left Turn, by t degrees and Right Turn by t degress respectively.

Answer (score 0):

In high school (liceo) I studied the inverse trigonometric functions, one of them the `arc tan(x)` or simply `atan(x)` — its meaning being, the angle `t` whose tangent is equal to `x`.  The implied limits are -infinity ≤ `x` ≤ + infinity  and -pi/2 ≤ `t` ≤ pi/2.

So, what is `atan2(x, y)`? It's a similar function that returns the angle `t`, -pi ≤ `t` ≤ pi, that is comprised between the unit vector in the horizontal direction and the vector `OP`, with `P=(x,y)`.

Why this fuction is called `atan2`? because it has TWO arguments (`atan` has a single argument) and because you can compute `atan2` using `atan`

```
atan2(x, y) <equiv> atan(y/x) or atan(y/x) ± pi
```

where you have to choose the particular solution based on the signs of `x` and `y` — this logic is no difficult but someone (possibly the implementors of first FORTRAN compilers?) decided that it was a so common question that it deserved a function on its own.

Another feature of `atan2` is that the overflow that follows when `x==0` is completely avoided,